# Neo4j performance discrepancies local vs cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, neo4j, virtual-machine

I am encountering drastic performance differences between a local Neo4j instance running on a VirtualBox-hosted VM and a basically identical Neo4j instance hosted in Google Cloud (GCP).  The task involves performing a simple load from a Postgres instance also located in GCP.  The entire load takes 1-2 minutes on the VirtualBox-hosted VM instance and 1-2 hours on the GCP VM instance.  The local hardware setup is a 10-year-old 8 core, 16GB desktop running VirtualBox 6.1.

With both VirtualBox and GCP I perform these similar tasks:

1. provision a 4 core, 8GB Ubuntu 18 LTS instance
2. install Neo4j Community Edition 4.0.2
3. use wget to download the latest apoc and postgres jdbc jars into the plugins dir
4. (only in GCP is the neo4j.conf file changed from defaults. I uncomment the "dbms.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0" line to permit non-localhost connections.  Corresponding GCP firewall rule also created)
5. restart neo4j service
6. install and start htop and iotop for hardware monitoring
7. login to empty neo4j instance via broswer console
8. load jdbc driver and run load statement

The load statement uses apoc.periodic.iterate to call apoc.load.jdbc.  I've varied the "batchSize" parameter in both environments from 100-10000 but only saw marginal changes in either system.  The "parallel" parameter is set to false because true causes lock errors.

Watching network I/O, both take the first ~15-25 seconds to pull the ~700k rows (8 columns) from the database table.  Watching CPU, both keep one core maxed at 100% while another core varies from 0-100%.  Watching memory, neither takes more than 4GB and swap stays at 0.  Initially, I did use the config recommendations from "neo4j-admin memrec" but those didn't seem to significantly change anything either in mem usage or overall execution time.

Watching disk, that is where there are differences.  But I think these are symptoms and not the root cause: the local VM consistently writes 1-2 MB/s throughout the entire execution time (1-2 minutes).  The GCP VM burst writes 300-400 KB/s for 1 second every 20-30 seconds.  But I don't think the GCP disks are slow or the problem (I've tried with both GCP's standard disk and their SSD disk).  If the GCP disks were slow, I would expect to see sustained write activity and a huge write-to-disk queue.  It seems whenever something should be written to disk, it gets done quickly in GCP.  It seems the bottleneck is before the disk writes.

All I can think of are that my 10-year-old cores are way faster than a current GCP vCPU, or that there is some memory heap thing going on.  I don't know much about java except heaps are important and can be finicky.

Comment: Do you have the exact same :schema on both systems? If you're missing a critical index used in your LOAD query that could easily explain the differences you're seeing. For example, if you're using a MATCH or a MERGE on a node by a certain property, it's the difference between doing a quick lookup of the node via the index, or performing a label scan of all nodes of that label checking every single one to see if the node exists or if it's the right node. Understand also that this process repeats for every single row, so in the worst case it's not a single label scan, it's n times that.

Comment: 1. Do you have the same number of cores and the same amount of RAM on your VirtualBox VM and GCP VM? 2. Do you use SSD or HDD on your local machine?

Comment: Have a look at [Storage options](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks) and [Performance of Zonal Persistent disks (Standard and SSD)](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#performance) "Persistent disk performance is predictable and scales linearly with provisioned capacity until the limits for an instance's provisioned vCPUs are reached" and "When you need more disk space or better performance, resize your disks and possibly add more vCPUs to add more storage space, throughput, and IOPS" Also check [Local SSDs](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#localssds). Choose proper

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I believe you are correct, my local instance does have several indexes (that I thought I had dropped long ago).  The GCP instance would not.  I'll prove out your theory today.  And then accept your answer if I have the option.  I'm new so I don't see an accept answer feature.

Comment: @InverseFalcon your recommendation worked.  Applying those indexes into the GCP cloud caused it to complete in the same time as the local instance.  I would accept your answer but I do not appear to have the privileges.

Comment: I just converted my comment to an answer, see if you're able to accept that.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have the exact same :schema on both systems? If you're missing a critical index used in your LOAD query that could easily explain the differences you're seeing.

For example, if you're using a MATCH or a MERGE on a node by a certain property, it's the difference between doing a quick lookup of the node via the index, or performing a label scan of all nodes of that label checking every single one to see if the node exists or if it's the right node. Understand also that this process repeats for every single row, so in the worst case it's not a single label scan, it's n times that.